# about synchronization with two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Say one singleton instance accessed by two threads. Two threads are accessing the same function called `doTask()`.

```
public class MySingleton {
    Object lock = new Object();
    // I omit the constructor here.

    public void doTask() {
         //first non-synchronized code

         synchronize(lock) {
             //some heavy task
         }

         //final non-synchronized code
    }
}
```

If thread B is doing the heavy task, when thread A access `doTask()`, I know **Thread A** will run the `//first non-synchronized code`, then **thread A** noticed the `lock` is acquired by **Thread B**, so it can't run synchronized `//some heavy task`. But would **thread A** skip the synchronized heavy task continue run `//final non-synchronized code` or will **thread A** wait for the lock without even executing the `//final non-synchronized code`?

(I know I can try it out, but currently I don't have a proper development environment...)

Comment: it will wait until B has finished and removed the lock

Comment: Your singleton's constructor is missing.

Answer (score 2):

The `synchronized` block in java forces threads to wait until they can acquire the object's lock.

It will wait until B is done, and then snag the lock for `lock`, and run the code inside the block, and continue out the other end.

It is important to note that when B finishes executing the contents of `some heavy task` it will release the lock on `lock` and run the `final non-synchronized code` at the "same time" that A runs the synchronized block.

Comment: "At the same time"  is slightly misleading here, the JVM is free to move the bits before and after the `synchronized` block inside the block, so long as it doesn't break any other reordering guarantees (such as given with a volatile read/write for example). A more precise way of putting it is that there is no guarantee that Thread A will see any of the changes made in `final non-synchronized code` executed by Thread B.

Comment: Yes, hence the quotes around "same time" ;)

Answer (score 0):

When one thread acquires the monitor of synchronous object, then the remaining threads will also try to acquire it and this process is termed as POLLING. Because all the remaining threads try to acquire the monitor of that object by repeatedly checking the monitor lock status. The moment when the lock is released it can be acquired by any thread. It's actually decided by the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Thread A will always wait indefinitely until Thread B releases the lock.

In the extreme case, if the lock is never released, Thread A will be stuck forever.

Sometimes this is good enough but often you will need better control over things, this is when classes like [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) come handy.

This can do everything `synchronized` offers, but can also do things like checking whether the lock is owned by the current thread already, attempting to acquire the lock without waiting (failing instantly if the lock is already taken by another thread), or limit its waiting to a certain amount of time.

Please also note that while these solutions can be used to control mutual exclusion, this isn't their only function, they also play an important role in visibility.